# groovy script variable with quotation

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I'm writing a jenkins File with groovy script.
I want to add to one of my variable quotation, and than echo this with shell.

my code:

```
VARIABLE="\"" + "i love you" + "\""
sh "echo ${VARIABLE}"
```

output:

```
i love you
```

desired output:

```
"i love you"
```

thanks!

Comment: you can try `VARIABLE="\\\"i love you\\\""`

Comment: or `VARIABLE='"i love you"'`